# afterLayout vs layout, afterRender vs render, etc. in ExtJS?

Tags: javascript, extjs

What is the difference between events like afterLayout and layout, afterRender and render? I understand the difference between beforeLayout and afterLayout -- but how does layout event differ?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Note: Applies to Ext 3.x only. This was answered in 2010.

There is no 'layout' event, only `afterLayout`.  From the docs, afterLayout "Fires when the components in this container are arranged by the associated layout manager" which is pretty self-explanatory.  `afterLayout` is only fired by Container subclasses that are responsible for laying out child components.

One the other hand, all Component subclasses (including Containers) fire the `render` and `afterRender` events.  The basic difference is simply that `afterRender` fires later.  `render` fires after the DOM markup is finished rendering, but before other things that might happen (like hiding, disabling, state-restoration, etc.) during the rendering process.  `afterRender` fires as the very last event after all of that is complete. To fully understand this you should look at the source for the `Ext.Component.render()` method, which shows step-by-step how the rendering process works and when these events are fired.